# How to Use Guice With Jersey JdkHttpServerFactory?

Tags: java, rest, http, guice, jersey-2.0

This is a **Java SE** application. I want to exclusively use Guice for my injection. I've read about the HK2 binder and I'd rather just use Guice. I'm familiar with Guice and use it regularly, but I can't figure out where to get things started with this and nearly all my Google-fu leads to container based jersey servers. I'm also NOT interested in Grizzly.

So how do I implement this so that I can use Guice for my injection needs?

```
import java.net.URI;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;

import org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.roycat.rnotes.ws.guice.MainModule;
import com.roycat.rnotes.ws.server.CustomResourceConfig;

public class StartRestServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String base = "localhost";
        Integer port = 8090;

        if (args.length == 1) {
            base = args[0];
        } else if (args.length == 2) {
            base = args[0];
            port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        }       

        URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://" + base
                      + "/").port(port).build();
        ResourceConfig config = new CustomResourceConfig();
        JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(baseUri, config);

        System.out.println("Server running on " + baseUri.toString() 
            + "...");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the HK2 [guice-bridge](https://hk2.java.net/2.4.0-b07/guice-bridge.html) to bridge Guice services to HK2.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-b31</version>
</dependency>
```

Note the `<version>` should match the HK2 version pulled in by your Jersey version. Just look at the HK2 jars that Jersey pulls in. It should have the version. In my case, I was using Jersey 2.22.1, which pull in HK2 2.4.0-b31

Then you need to code the bridge. I just did it in a `Feature`

```
@Priority(1)
public class GuiceFeature implements Feature {

    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorProvider.getServiceLocator(context);
        GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(locator);
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyGuiceModule());
        GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = locator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
        guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(injector);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then register the feature with your `ResourceConfig`

```
config.register(GuiceFeature.class);
```

Now you should be able to inject the Guice services into your Jersey components.

---

#### UPDATE

Here is a complete working test

```
import com.google.inject.AbstractModule;
import com.google.inject.Guice;
import com.google.inject.Injector;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.hk2.api.ServiceLocator;
import org.glassfish.jersey.ServiceLocatorProvider;
import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jdkhttp.JdkHttpServerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.jvnet.hk2.guice.bridge.api.GuiceBridge;
import org.jvnet.hk2.guice.bridge.api.GuiceIntoHK2Bridge;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class JdkHttpGuiceTest {

    @Priority(1)
    public static class GuiceFeature implements Feature {
        @Override
        public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
            ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorProvider.getServiceLocator(context);
            GuiceBridge.getGuiceBridge().initializeGuiceBridge(locator);
            Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new EncoderModule());
            GuiceIntoHK2Bridge guiceBridge = locator.getService(GuiceIntoHK2Bridge.class);
            guiceBridge.bridgeGuiceInjector(injector);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static interface Encoder {
        String encode(String value);
    }

    public static class UppercaseEncoder implements Encoder {
        @Override
        public String encode(String value) {
            return value.toUpperCase();
        }
    }

    static class EncoderModule extends AbstractModule {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(Encoder.class).to(UppercaseEncoder.class);
        } 
    }

    @Path("test")
    public static class TestResource {
        @Inject
        private Encoder encoder;

        @GET
        public String get(@QueryParam("s") String s) {
            return encoder.encode(s);
        }
    }

    public static class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
        public AppConfig() {
            register(TestResource.class);
            register(GuiceFeature.class);
            register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));
        }
    }

    private HttpServer server;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        server = JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
                URI.create("http://localhost:8080/"), new AppConfig());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        server.stop(1);
        server = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void injectionShouldWork() {
        final Response response = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://localhost:8080/test")
                .queryParam("s", "hello")
                .request().get();
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        assertEquals("HELLO", response.readEntity(String.class));
    }
}
```

Dependencies used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
    <artifactId>guice-bridge</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0-b31</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-jdk-http</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That sort of works. I'm trying to inject a service into the resource class (the class with the @GET etc). If I do a field, or method injection with Guice, it doesn't inject. If I do a constructor injection with Guice, it injects, but of course it throws exceptions because it requires a no arg constructor. So how do I inject it into the resource class?

Comment: Maybe the configuration inside the `Feature` is not the best solution, but from what I remember testing, I think I did use constructor injection.  As for the the method injection, that requires a completely different mechanism, that it kind on unrelated to the usual DI from HK2. If you use `@Context` next to the method parameter, it may work. I don't have my IDE open right now to test these things out.

Comment: I will play around with it a little bit later and let you know what I come up with

Comment: I believe I'm registering the resource as a class. In the CustomResourceConfig I'm registering it as super.register(NoteController.class); where the CustomResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig.

Also, when I used constructor injection it did work, sending the json to the client, but it still threw the no arg constructor exceptions.

Comment: One thing I would make sure of is that you are using the `@javax.inject.Inject` and not the google annotation. I've just tested with both field and constructor, and it works fine.

Comment: That was it. I left everything else the same, but switched from `@com.google.inject.Inject` to `@javax.inject.inject` and it worked like a champ. Thanks so much for your help!